# Highlight cells based on date AND cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am stuck on a formula for the conditional cell formatting. I want to highlight cells based on "AND" rule of these two conditions:

- In cell H3 I have % values. I want to highlight cell where value is below 90%.

AND

- In cell B3 I have date formatted as MM/DD/YYYY. I want to highlight cell when the current date is one day before compared date in B3.

I tried:

```
=AND(H3<90,B3 < TODAY()-1)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Here is [an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xv_W91Ffgt7pyv8EgT5ST8XWcH6B4Z7AZd97aFR2Ftw/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Works good here. Provide your Google sheet or a dummy sheet with that problem reproduced.

Comment: hmm, strange. Here is link to desired table > https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xv_W91Ffgt7pyv8EgT5ST8XWcH6B4Z7AZd97aFR2Ftw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Works fine and as intended. However this might be the formula you're looking for:

```
  =AND(H3<90,(B3-1) <=TODAY())
```